# Can I update my Galaxy Nexus manually?

Tags: updates, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I am having a problem with music playback stutter on my Galaxy Nexus, and after searching about it for a while, it seems the problem was fixed on update 4.0.4.

Unfortunately, my phone is still on 4.0.2 and no OTA Update is currently available.

From past experiences with my Milestone, updating or using a ROM that was not originally from my country (Brazil) resulted in various problems, including no 3G connection and very poor GPS signal.

Is it possible to actually update the Galaxy Nexus manually from 4.0.2 to 4.0.4? If yes, is there a way to know which "version" of the system would be compatible with mine?

Here's the "About Phone" tab on settings:

[image]

Comment: I just want to be sure, but you have the GSM Galaxy Nexus, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the 4.0.4 is currently only available for the CDMA/LTE, but [someone over at Modaco](http://android.modaco.com/topic/351478-14-feb-ir11-beta-2-imm30b-404-cdma-gsm-modaco-custom-rom-for-the-galaxy-nexus/) has a modified version of the 4.0.4 working for GSM.

It looks like everything is working on the GSM version with this modified release. I have [also read](http://www.techzek.com/android-4-0-5-ics-for-galaxy-nexus-gsm-coming-in-march/) that 4.0.5 will be released next month, so you may want to just wait.

Comment: Thanks! The music bug is gone on the modified 4.0.4 GSM update. I had to flash the stock Google rom (yakju) before being able to do it though (discovered mine was yakjuvs through [this app](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.cbruegg.officialupdate). I think that would be the biggest limitation in respect to updating different versions of the phone.